# How to display soft deleted items in symfony2 sonata project list?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

Now if the item is deleted it is removed from the list.

Is there any possibility to display deleted items in sonata project list?

Comment: if its soft delete than it should be change from Database.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without code. But SonataAdminORMBundle is adding a new attribute to your entity. A soft delete is just passing the property `enabled` to false. So if you want to print all your deleted projects, just make a request on your project repository on `enabled = 0`.